# What could cause socketConnect to hang

Tags: tomcat, websphere

I'm running a web application in tomcat (from within eclipse) in my win7 laptop, connecting to a websphere server in a remote lab. I'm able to invoke some of the APIs of my middleware installed there, but others aren't able to respond. I can see in SystemOut.log the following log:

```
[1/24/12 20:16:51:434 EET] 00000046 ThreadMonitor W   WSVR0605W: Thread "ORB.thread.pool : 0" (0000004e) has been active for 621039 milliseconds and may be hung.  There is/are 3 thread(s) in total in the server that may be hung.
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:413)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:274)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:261)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:389)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:556)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:504)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:412)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:226)
        at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTCPTransportConnection.createSocket(WSTCPTransportConnection.java:371)
        at com.ibm.CORBA.transport.TransportConnectionBase.connect(TransportConnectionBase.java:356)
        at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTransport.getConnection(WSTransport.java:429)
        at com.ibm.CORBA.transport.TransportBase.getConnection(TransportBase.java:187)
        at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.TransportManager.get(TransportManager.java:93)
        at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.GIOPImpl.getConnection(GIOPImpl.java:129)
        at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.GIOPImpl.locate(GIOPImpl.java:205)
        at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.locate(ClientDelegate.java:1966)
        at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate._createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1991)
        at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1155)
        at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1270)
        at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1327)
        at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1131)
        at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1293)
        at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.request(ClientDelegate.java:1869)
        at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.request(ClientDelegate.java:1249)
        at org.omg.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._request(ObjectImpl.java:458)
        at com.ibm.org.omg.SendingContext._CodeBaseStub.meta(_CodeBaseStub.java:116)
        at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.FVDCodeBaseDelegate.meta(FVDCodeBaseDelegate.java:145)
        at com.ibm.rmi.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObjectFVD(IIOPInputStream.java:1591)
        at com.ibm.rmi.io.IIOPInputStream.readSerializable(IIOPInputStream.java:1153)
        at com.ibm.rmi.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObjectInternal(IIOPInputStream.java:427)
        at com.ibm.rmi.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObjectLoop(IIOPInputStream.java:510)
        at com.ibm.rmi.io.IIOPInputStream.readObjectDelegate(IIOPInputStream.java:375)
        at com.ibm.rmi.io.IIOPInputStream.readObjectOverride(IIOPInputStream.java:633)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
        at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:617)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor113.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
        at com.ibm.rmi.io.IIOPInputStream.invokeObjectReader(IIOPInputStream.java:1772)
        at com.ibm.rmi.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObjectUsingClassDesc(IIOPInputStream.java:1507)
        at com.ibm.rmi.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObjectClassDesc(IIOPInputStream.java:1482)
        at com.ibm.rmi.io.IIOPInputStream.readSerializable(IIOPInputStream.java:1155)
        at com.ibm.rmi.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObjectInternal(IIOPInputStream.java:427)
        at com.ibm.rmi.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObjectLoop(IIOPInputStream.java:510)
        at com.ibm.rmi.io.IIOPInputStream.readObjectDelegate(IIOPInputStream.java:375)
        at com.ibm.rmi.io.IIOPInputStream.readObjectOverride(IIOPInputStream.java:633)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
        at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:617)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor113.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
        at com.ibm.rmi.io.IIOPInputStream.invokeObjectReader(IIOPInputStream.java:1772)
        at com.ibm.rmi.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObjectUsingClassDesc(IIOPInputStream.java:1507)
        at com.ibm.rmi.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObjectClassDesc(IIOPInputStream.java:1482)
        at com.ibm.rmi.io.IIOPInputStream.readSerializable(IIOPInputStream.java:1155)
        at com.ibm.rmi.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObjectInternal(IIOPInputStream.java:427)
        at com.ibm.rmi.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObjectLoop(IIOPInputStream.java:510)
        at com.ibm.rmi.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:464)
        at com.ibm.rmi.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:209)
        at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.CDRInputStream.read_value(CDRInputStream.java:2195)
        at com.ejb._EJSRemoteStatelessMyBean_415f1de0_Tie.run__com_interfaces_RV__boolean__long__boolean__boolean__CORBA_WStringValue(_EJSRemoteStatelessMyBean_415f1de0_Tie.java:220)
        at com.ejb._EJSRemoteStatelessMyBean_415f1de0_Tie._invoke(_EJSRemoteStatelessMyBean_415f1de0_Tie.java:126)
        at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatchInvokeHandler(ServerDelegate.java:627)
        at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatch(ServerDelegate.java:480)
        at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:512)
        at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:1571)
        at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.respondTo(Connection.java:2665)
        at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.doWork(Connection.java:2530)
        at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.WorkUnitImpl.doWork(WorkUnitImpl.java:62)
        at com.ibm.ejs.oa.pool.PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:118)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1551)
```

In my web client i don't get any kind of logs or exception. Only for some APIs this happens. I'm clueless here!

Comment: Are there any blue coat proxies between client and server?

Comment: What does not responding look like? The client just hangs? Can you force a thread dump on the WebSphere server? That particular log message, I think, comes from WebSphere detecting a hung thread, but doesn't tell you what that thread is doing. The thread dump could tell you that.

Comment: I have tried this targeting 3 different test labs in 3 different networks, two of which i need to open a firewall to connect to, and one in my own network. The result is the same. 
My client just hangs. I can try to force the thread dump. Thanks for the tips.